# Can accordian control main category href work?

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, nav

When clicking the category, the accordion works, and the subcategories are listed in nav tab. But the href of category doesn't work. Links for subcategories work fine.
The category link should work and display all the products in that category thus listing every subcategory.

```
<a class='nav-link collapsed'  href='../account/MarketPlace.aspx?Category1' data-toggle='collapse' 
 data-target='#collapseLayouts' aria-expanded='false'  aria-controls='collapseLayouts'> --category
   <div class='sidenav-collapse-arrow'>  
</a>
<div class='collapse' id='collapseLayouts' data-parent='#accordionSidenav'>
   <nav class='sidenav-menu-nested nav accordion' id='accordionSidenavLayout'>
     <a class='nav-link' href='../account/MarketPlace.aspx? Category=Category1&SubCategory=subcat1'></a> -subcategory1
     <a class='nav-link' href='../account/MarketPlace.aspx?Category=Category1&SubCategory=subcat2'></a> -subcategory2
     <a class='nav-link' href='../account/MarketPlace.aspx?Category=Category1&SubCategory=subcat3'></a> -subcategory3
   </nav>
</div>
```

If the link worked, when clicking the category, all the products will be listed( tested it by hardcoding it in URL).
How can I correct it? Please help?

Comment: Please clarify: You want the hyperlink that currently expands your accordion to ALSO function as a normal hyperlink? That seems counterintuitive to having a collapsible selection as clicking the hyperlink would then... take you to another page and thus stopping the collapsed information from ever displaying.

Comment: I want the hyperlink to take me to another page at the same time display the collapsed information. Can it be done? @Robert

Comment: If the hyperlink functioned like a normal hyperlink you would be taken to a new page, meaning the collapsed information would be displayed only for so long as it took your browser to process the page load request... effectively eliminating the purpose of a collapsible menu entirely.